# Django Groups not updating when saving User

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

I'm trying to add users that belong to staff to the staff group on change. I've tried it with signals and by overloading save in the User model but neither of them seem to work. Does django has any limitations I'm not aware of when saving?

Here are both code snippets I tried to work with. User is inherited from the AbstractUser and used with the new Django 1.5 feature AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User', Groups are standard auth groups.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, **kwargs):
        if self.is_staff:
            if not self.groups.filter(name='staff').exists():
                g = Group.objects.get(name='staff')
                g.user_set.add(self)
        else:
            if self.groups.filter(name='staff').exists():
                g = Group.objects.get(name='staff')
                g.user_set.remove(self)

        super(User, self).save(force_insert, force_update)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs['instance']
    if user.is_staff:
        if not user.groups.filter(name='staff').exists():
            g = Group.objects.get(name='staff')
            g.user_set.add(user)
    else:
        if user.groups.filter(name='staff').exists():
            g = Group.objects.get(name='staff')
            g.user_set.remove(user)
```

Comment: I think it's because of this one: if not user.groups.filter(name='staff').exists():. What's that line mean? You're filtering if staff exist but you already put if user.is_staff

Comment: seems ok. Try another way: if not self.groups.filter(name='staff').exists(): self.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='staff'))

Answer (score 3):

If you use a `form(ModelForm)` then the reason for disappearing group might be a `form.save_m2m()` that is called after your `user.save()`. For example, if you have an empty "groups" field in your form, `save_m2m` just removes all groups from you user.

Comment: I've spent hours chasing this :( as I was adding a new user from the Admin page and a `User.post_save` connected signal is adding the user to a group which never happens!
This makes now perfect sense because when using the API to create the user, I can see the user added to the expected group!
Thanks!